# Access WebView2 newly opened window

Tags: chromium, webview2

If I run `window.open("url")` it will open url in new *popup window*, even if it is Edge WebView2. It will just have default Windows title-bar, and read-only url bar. I need to open url from WebView exactly in new popup window, via `window.open("url")`.

Is there any way to access that window from my program as far as original WebView2 child-window? By accessing I mean injecting scripts, and getting js-response after injecting.

Or, at least, perhaps there is way to open url with some pre-injected script, like `window.open("http://google.com -javascript: alert(5)")`?

---

## Update

Found [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-488/icorewebview2#add_newwindowrequested), probably this is what do I need. Trying to understand that.

Comment: `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreated` might be what you want, just look further down that page.

Comment: @PoulBak it might be solution, I will try

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [`ICoreWebView2::add_NewWindowRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-622/icorewebview2#add_newwindowrequested) event lets you intercept WebView2 opening new windows.

If you do nothing in the event handler, or don't subscribe to the event, you'll get a new popup like you describe. In script the return value of `window.open` is connected up to the newly opened popup window. But in your native code you have no access to or control over the newly opened window.

Or you can set the [`Handled` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-488/icorewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs) to true on the NewWindowRequested event's args, and no new window will be created. This is useful if you want to prevent opening windows or if you want to send new window opens to the default browser or somewhere else. In script the return value of `window.open` is null.

Or you can provide your own ICoreWebView2 via the [`NewWindow` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-488/icorewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs). In this case you are responsible for and get to choose how to host that ICoreWebView2 in some manner. The ICoreWebView2 you provide as the NewWindow will be the target of the new window navigation and connected back up via script to the return value of the `window.open` call.

Because obtaining a new WebView2 may require asynchronous method calls, you can use the GetDeferral method on the event args to stop the completion of the window requested event until you call Complete on the deferral asynchronously later.

You can see a [working sample of the `add_NewWindowRequested` event](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/0e6587d15e0c50762639146868d7d637d96ae936/SampleApps/WebView2APISample/AppWindow.cpp) in our sample app.

Comment: Actually, the reason why I need to do that is a bug in exactly WebView. I can’t demonstrate it because the site where bug is appears need to be log in. In a nutshell, this is an ASP.Net site that works well in Edge Beta browser, but in WebView2, when I click buttons that should do ajax `__postback`, showing the loading dialog, the dialog doesn’t appear, although request is sent. So in case of there are some additional steps after postback, the site is breaks. If not, I can refresh WebView and see changes.

Comment: So I decided, for steps where postbacks don’t have additional actions after it use WebView2 and then call `window.open(document.location)`, find new window via WinApi, hide it, and then send `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` to click on buttons I need. It very bad solution, but yet solution

Comment: @david risney - If I handle the new window myself with a new corewebview2 (I'm opening a new form and adding the webview2 control), is there a way that I can allow a window.close in the child window without getting the "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them" error? I'll create a new question if you prefer

Comment: Maybe a new question would be good. Not sure I understand fully which window is calling close